# asp.net web api authentication with retrofit

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, retrofit

I am working on an android app and for web services I have use asp.net mvc and for post and get data from api I have user retrofit. how to authenticate user using api so that only authenticated user can access my web api

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **token** authentication like **JWT**.

In this approach, you'll log in and give a JWT token back. With each GET/POST request, you should pass that token in **Authorization Header** and in the server, you should authorize this token.

Authorizing the token could be done using built-in Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET MVC.

This article will help you get started : [ASP.NET Core JWT Authentication](https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login)